# Получить значение с MySQL и сразу же удалить строку

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо из таблицы MySQL значение и сразу же удалить эту строку. Сейчас делаю через 2 запроса:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `data` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
list ($my_data) = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
var_dump($my_data);
```

Можно ли SELECT и DELETE объединить в один запрос, но при этом и получить значение? Идентификация по переменной my_id. Заранее спасибо

Comment: В MySQL нельзя, разве что напишите хранимую процедуру, которая выполнит те же 2 запроса

Answer (score -1):

В множестве SQL выделяют подмножество DQL - Data query language - и DML - Data manipulation language. Первый предназначен для получения данных, второй - для манипуляций над ними. И хорошей практикой будет не пытаться их смешивать.
Если же это действительно необходимо, следует написать хранимую процедуру, которая будет возврашать и удалять данные. Чтобы предотвратить возможность одновременного доступа к строке нескольким клиентам, используйте row lock внутри ХП.